# Inserting a string with double quotes into a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 10g and I'm having a problem inserting a string with double quotes into a table. This is my statement

```
INSERT INTO USERS (ID, NAME, USERNAME) VALUES (NULL, "tes", "hello");
```

The query above fails with the error *"Oracle column not allowed here"*.

If I change double quotes to single quotes, as below the statement is successful.

```
INSERT INTO USERS (ID, NAME, USERNAME) VALUES (NULL, 'tes', 'hello');
```

But, I want to insert the double quotes into the table.

Is it possible to have double quote in strings in an insert statement? I don't want to use REPLACE() because my query is automatically generated from an array.

Comment: You need to insert value `"tes"` right?

Comment: have you tried to escape it?, for example "\"tes\"" , does it work?

Answer (score 17):

A double quote is used to denote a [quoted identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129), i.e. an object name that does not solely consist of alpha-numeric characters, `$` and `#`. As an aside, it's recommended that you do *not* use quoted identifiers. This is the reason for your original ORA-00984 error. Oracle is assuming that `"tes"` is a column, not a string, and you can't use a column name in the VALUES clause of an INSERT statement, [as explained in the error message](http://ora-00984.ora-code.com/).

In order to insert the *string* `"tes"` into a table you need to ensure that it is [quoted correctly](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/tablecls.htm#CNCPT1821):

> Character literals are enclosed in single quotation marks so that the database can distinguish them from schema object names.

Any character can be part of a string so in order to insert a double quote into a table you need to enclose it within single quotes.

```
insert into users (id, name, username) 
values (null, '"tes"', '"hello"');
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56668/1) to demonstrate.

---

One additional thing to note. You state that this query is automatically generated, which means you *may* be vulnerable to SQL injection. I would highly recommend reading about bind variables in [Guarding Against SQL Injection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS645).

Answer (score 12):

It is possible. In Oracle, you quote string literals using single quotes.

If you want to insert `test` into the database then you must quote that as `'test'`.

```
INSERT INTO USERS (NAME) VALUES ('test');
```

If you want to insert `"test"` into the database then you must quote that as `'"test"'`.

```
INSERT INTO USERS (NAME) VALUES ('"test"');
```

Comment: You can insert any character, but you have to use single quotes around them.

Comment: Jeffrey, I know it is possible to insert any quote as text into the database. But it's not possible to use double quote as the delimiter of the string.

Answer (score 6):

Try wrapping the values inside single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO USERS (ID, NAME, USERNAME) VALUES (NULL, '"tes"', '"hello"');
```

Comment: What if I need to only insert one double quote in between a string?